# What is the default value of android:vmSafeMode?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand a bit more about the JIT compiler optimization. Is this optimization automatically enabled? Why wouldn't I want this option enabled?

This is my manifest sdk target:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the JIT compiler optimizations are enabled which means the default vmSafeMode is set to "false", so by setting it to "true" you are turning off the JIT compiler.
Of course if the device is running an OS under API level 8 (froyo) which doesn't support JIT; it shouldn't make any difference.

*(sources:)*

[embedded-vm-control from the Android open source project](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/embedded-vm-control.html)

[Android 2.2 notes from developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.2.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had forgot about this question... :)

Comment: Now DALVIK is no longer the standard Android runtime, it should be noted that setting vmSafeMode to true will disable the ART ahead-of-time compiler at install time if you build with API 22+

Answer (score 1):

The JIT compiler can be disabled on a per-application basis ,default value is false for `android:vmSafeMode` by adding
        `android:vmSafeMode="true"` in the `application`
        tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` This can be useful if you
        suspect that JIT compilation is causing your application to behave
        incorrectly.

I hope this will help to understand more about `android:vmSafeMode`